# Remove duplicates based on one column, then move the "older" duplicate to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with data columns A through H. I need to remove duplicates based on data in column C.

The tricky part is that I have a date in column E. I need the "older" duplicate to be moved to another sheet, not deleted.

I have a macro to move duplicates to another sheet, but it's selection on what stays/goes is random.

Requested edit: It's not that this macro is wrong, it's that I don't know how to make it move the older duplicate based on date in column E.

```
Sub DupMove()
Dim t As Single
Dim d As Object, x&, xcol As String
Dim lc&, lr&, k(), e As Range
xcol = "C"
lc = Cells.Find("*", after:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
lr = Cells.Find("*", after:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ReDim k(1 To lr, 1 To 1)
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each e In Cells(1, xcol).Resize(lr)
    If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then
        d(e.Value) = 1
        k(e.Row, 1) = 1
    End If
Next e
Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(lr) = k
Range("A1", Cells(lr, lc + 1)).Sort Cells(1, lc + 1), 1
x = Cells(1, lc + 1).End(4).Row
Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Copy Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A1")
Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Clear
Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(x).Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `macros` tag.  If you are unsure, read the tag info associated with [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. First of all, I'm no at all a VBA guru, so many things might be wrong. I kept most of your code, but in the Dictionary(`d`), I'm adding not only the value, but also an Array with the row number and the value in column E. In this way, when the loop reaches a cell that is already in the dictionary, instead of skipping it you can test the two ColumnE values, and decides which one to keep.

```
Sub DupMove()
    Dim t As Single
    Dim d As Object, x&, xcol As String
    Dim lc&, lr&, k(), e As Range
    xcol = "C"
    lc = Cells.Find("*", after:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    lr = Cells.Find("*", after:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ReDim k(1 To lr, 1 To 1)
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each e In Cells(1, xcol).Resize(lr)
        If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then   'If not in dictionary, add it
            d.Add e.Value, Array(Cells(e.Row, 5), e.Row)    'Add the value, and an Array with column E (5) data and number of row
            k(e.Row, 1) = 1
        Else                            'If already in dictionary, test the new column E value with that saved in the array
            If d(e.Value)(0).Value < Cells(e.Row, 5).Value Then
                k(d(e.Value)(1), 1) = ""
                k(e.Row, 1) = 1
                d(e.Value)(0) = Cells(e.Row, 5)
                d(e.Value)(1) = e.Row
            End If

        End If
    Next e

    Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(lr) = k
    Range("A1", Cells(lr, lc + 1)).Sort Cells(1, lc + 1), 1
    x = Cells(1, lc + 1).End(4).Row
    Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Copy Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A1")
    Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Clear
    Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(x).Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you immensely.